# Initialize and Compare Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

This is a piece of code that works. I want to believe that valid is initialized to error if error is equivalent to null else it is undefined. Is that correct?

```
const { error } = schema.validate(req.body);
  const valid = error == null;

  if (valid) {

  } else {

  }
```

Comment: `valid is initialized to error if error is equivalent to null` --> no, `valid` is initialized to `true` or `false`, depending whether `error == null`

Comment: And valid initially is false?

Comment: ... if `error != null` yes

Answer (score 1):

`valid` it's the result of the evaluation of `error == null`, nothing more. You can deconstruct the code to make it more easy to understand (like below), without changing its meaning.

```
const valid = error == null;
```

is semantically equal (beside the possibility of reassignment) to:

```
let valid;

if (error == null) {
   valid = true;
} else {
   valid = false;
}
```